# Is it possible in android to add app icon to status bar?

Tags: android, android-notifications

Is it possible in android to add app icon to status bar, similar to wifi/bluetooth icon? I know it can be done using Status Bar Notification, but it gets cleared when we clear notification. Can I show icon permanently on status bar?

Comment: Post the solution or the snippet of you've solved your issue

Answer (score 0):

To keep the icon there until you clear it you can do the following:

```
 Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "", when_to_display);
 notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Then you must clear it. There are other flags too, all described here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html

Comment: Thanks David for the reply. I figured it out. I am now using flag on_going so that the icon just remains in the tray

Comment: Yeah looking at my answer in hindsight shows it really didn't answer your question that flag (AUTO_CANCEL) was definitely not the one you were looking for.